# Regex findall matches letters "a" to "z" in a string followed by another character

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, findall, python-re

Result should return list which contains letter a to c followed by another character

Text is aabbcc I would expect it return ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']

```
import re
text = 'aabbcc'
result = re.findall(r'([a-c]).', text)
print(result)
```

but it returns ['a', 'b', 'c']

Comment: `findall` returns **non-overlapping** matches.

Comment: You need `[a-c](?!$)` or `(?s)[a-c](?=.)`

Answer (score 2):

Use a non-capturing lookahead (`[a-z](?=.)`). This is basically the same as what you had, but doesn't capture the next character.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work the way you have it, simply import `regex` instead of `re` module and use the `overlapped` parameter:

```
import regex
text = 'aabbcc'
result = regex.findall(r'([a-c]).', text, overlapped = True)
print(result)
```

Prints:

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']
```

Otherwise a positive lookahead mentioned in comments and other answers is an option.

Comment: perfect!! what is difference between both?

Comment: @SanatkumarWagh, [here](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) you can read about the `regex` module and the new vs old behaviour. Please, if this has answered your question, dont'forget to upvote and/or accept the answer. Click the arrows on the left and the checkmark to the left of the answer.